# how does this small c# code work

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver

I joined a new team that automates using c# and selenium.
I cant follow how this line works:

```
   driver.FindElement(Elements.OkLink).click()
```

I know about why *driver* and *FindElement* are used . but i just cant figure out how *Elements.OkLink* is used. What is it a variable/object/method

This below line is where OkLink is actualy defined.

```
    public class Elements
    {
        public static By OkLink = By.LinkText("Ok");

    }
```

I found out the following definition from Selenium documentation:

```
  By.LinkText Method    

  Syntax:

   public static By LinkText(
string linkTextToFind
    )

   Return Value: A By object the driver can use to find the elements.
```

By is actually a class . Is LinkText a method. I thought methods are similar to functions. How is *ClassName MethodName* is used here.

Comment: What exactly is confusing you?

Answer (score 2):

> Is LinkText a method.

Yes.

> I thought methods are similar to functions.

That's right.

> How is ClassName MethodName is used here.

In the declaration? That just indicates what the method returns. So to pull this declaration apart:

```
public static By LinkText(string linkTextToFind)
```

- `public` means it can be called by any code, in any assembly
- `static` means the method is associated with the type rather than with any particular instance of the type. (It doesn't depend on an instance.) That's why it's called using the class name rather than via an instance - `By by = By.LinkText`.)
- `By` is the return type - the method will return a value of type `By` - a reference to a `By` object, or a null reference.
- `LinkText` is the name of the method
- `string linkTextToFind` is a parameter of type `string` with name `linkTextToFind`

Comment: thanks mate.. but from the documentation, By also seems to be a Class..
The selenium documetation say hese two about By
1)By is a class
2)The By type exposes the following methods (llinktest is one of them)..............
how does the By class set a return type for its methods or how does a class define what its methods should return

Comment: @user3083590: Yes... I never said it wasn't. What's confusing you at this point?

Comment: thanks mate.. but from the documentation The selenium documetation say hese two about By 1)By is a class 2)The By type exposes the following methods (llinktest is one of them).............. how does the By class set a return type for its methods or how does a class define what its methods should return

Comment: @user3083590: Each method declares its own return type. This is not specific to Selenium - it's basic C#. I suggest you put Selenium to one side for the moment and read a good introductory C# book, and all will become clear.

Answer (score 0):

In your case...it is just finding the button ok to click...for doing that we can general use find an element using link text OK...